# Installing O365 via powershell inside an ISO file

Tags: powershell, office365, iso-image, sccm

I created an Office 365 installer where it does the local installation and dynamically changes the SourcePath, and I need to run it from an ISO file (I normally use USB's, but in VM's I use ISO)

Running locally in any directory or USB it works perfectly, but from an ISO it doesn't, the error appears:

```
Set-Content : Access to path 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpoffice\configuration.xml' was denied. No E:\SMS\PKG\CM10017B\InstallOffice_OfflineMode.ps1:24 character:164
+ ... fficeMgmtCOM="TRUE" SourcePath="'+$PS1dirEOL) | Set-Content $tempconf
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

How do I get this to work also within an ISO? I know an ISO is read-only, but I thought it was strange that he would try to modify something that is not in the ISO but in a temporary directory and he still can't.

```
$PS1dir = Get-Location

#Paths of the configuration
$tempdir = "$env:TEMP\tmpoffice"
$conf = "$($PS1dir)\configuration.xml"
$tempconf = "$env:TEMP\tmpoffice\configuration.xml"

#Current path with reformated end of XML line
$PS1dirEOL = "$($PS1dir)`" `AllowCdnFallback=`"TRUE`">"

#Copy configuration file for temp folder and set variable for same
Copy-Item $conf -Destination (New-Item -Path $tempdir -Type Directory -Force) -Recurse -Force

#Replace old line with the current folder
(Get-Content $tempconf) -replace '<Add OfficeClientEdition=.*', ('<Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Current" OfficeMgmtCOM="TRUE" SourcePath="'+$PS1dirEOL) | Set-Content $tempconf

#Running O365 installation from new configuration file
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c start /MIN $($PS1dir)\setup.exe /configure $tempconf" -Wait

Remove-Item -Path $tempdir -Force -Recurse
```